# interstitial link open in webview not in browser

Tags: android, webview, admob, android-webview

In my app I am showing interstitial ad. Click on that ad I want to open that link in my app webview not in browser. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you must set your clients.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

you can also extend them and handle different things on your own.

Comment: But how to to open adlink in webview in app not in browser?

Comment: I know this-  webView.loadUrl("google.com"); How to get that URL of  interstitial ad?

Comment: I don't think it's allowed. Those ads communicate with users device through intent and URI through ContentProvider. I don't think admob allows to override that.